# Elements not being added to Linked List

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, linked-list

I am having trouble with elements not being added to my linked list. I have been able to varify that the char string is being scanned in main() properly as well as being copied over to the temp node however this is not being added to the linked list.

```
struct node{
    char string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    node *next;
};

void insertAsFirstElement(node *head, node *last, char string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH])
{

    //create temporary node
    node *temp = new node;

    printf("The temp's string before copy is %s.\n", temp->string);
    //this is the string copy from the user to the temp
    strcpy(temp->string, string);

    printf("The temp's string is %s.\n", temp->string);

    //set the next pointer to NULL (points to nothing)
    temp->next = NULL;
    //set first value in list to temp
    head = temp;
    //set last value to temp
    last = temp;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a good question. It's tough to see where your problem is when you just dump all of your code.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. This is C++, not C! You just mix in C coding style into C++ which is a very bad idea.

Comment: i agree with Tim and Olaf. You should not mix C and C++. Good solution proposed by Tim, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with the code you posted.

The first one is that your linked list does not contain a string, it contains an array of pointers.

You should omit the `*` in `char *string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];`

The second one is your call to `scanf`.

`scanf("%s\n", &string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]);`

This puts the program user's input into memory that comes after the string.
That's not what you want. You want the user's input to go into memory at the beginning of the string, like this:

`scanf("%s\n", &string[0]);`

Or written even simpler:

`scanf("%s\n", string);`

And lastly, you're not copying the string to linked list.
You can do that using `strcpy`, like this:

`strcpy(temp->string, string);`

Comment: Also a good thing to test `scanf`'s return value to ensure that a value was read and processed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I fixed all of your noticed issues. I also checked the scanf's values and did confirm it was scanning in the string and copying this string to the temp. After getting to that point It doesn't seem to want to add anything to the Linked List however.

Answer (score 1):

```
//this is the string copy from temp to new
char *strcpy(char *temp, const char string);
```

This *declares* the `strcpy` function. You want to *call* it.

```
strcpy(temp->string, string);
```

---

Please don't mix-and-match C and C++. They are very different languages. If you want to do this in C++, then it is incredibly easy.

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<std::string> strings;
    char choice = menu();

    while (choice != '4') {
        switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            std::string input;
            std::cout << "Please enter a string: ";
            std::cin >> input;
            strings.push_back(input);
            break;
        case '2':
            strings.pop_front();
            break;
        case '3':
            if (strings.size() == 0) {
                std::cout << "The list is empty.\n";
            } else {
                for (auto &s : strings) {
                    std::cout << s << "\n";
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "System Exit";
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help understand what's wrong with the code he posted.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Sorry. I think I had a copy-paste error. It should be fixed now.